# JSON can't be parsed using Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have the following JSON reply from a PHP file:

```
[
    {
        "color": "black",
        "product_name": "Prod2",
        "revision": "apps/"
    },
    {
        "color": "green",
        "product_name": "Prod1",
        "revision": "dev/"
    }
]
```

(tested OK on [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/))

And Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $('.target').keyup(function() {
        var package_name = "name";
        var package_version = "version";
        var filter_results = "filter";
        $.post('includes/package_filter.php', { package_name: package_name, package_version: package_version, filter_results: filter_results }, function(return_result) {                   
obj = JSON.parse(return_result);
alert(obj.product_name);
           var existingDiv = document.getElementById('other');
existingDiv.innerHTML = CreateTable(return_result); 
        });
    });
});
```

The return_result doesn't seem to be correct since I get `Error: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data` when doing the JSON.parse
I also don't go further to the alrt...
What could be wrong?

My PHP file is similar to:

```
<?php
function package_filter($package_name, $package_version, $filter_results){
    foreach ($descriptions as $descriptions_display) {
        ...
        $array_to_return[] = array('color' => $color , 'product_name' => $descriptions_display['product_name'] , 'revision' => $descriptions_display['revision']);
    }       
    return json_encode($array_to_return);
}
?>
```

My goal is to create a table with my `CreateTable` function but there is something wrong before.

Comment: The JSON string you posted is fine. There must be something else going on here.

Comment: Try using `eval('('+return_result+')')`.

Comment: Are you sure jQuery didn't notice that the response was JSON and already converted it to an object for you?

Comment: What is the `typeof return_result`? jQuery may have already parsed the response, so the `JSON.parse()` could be redundant.

Comment: @ChrisHayes: That typically results in a different error.

Comment: Did you get a look to the browser page source of your php page?

Comment: With the inspector of the browser, what is the exact content returned by the PHP page? There could be some hidden characters, maybe, that you can't see on your screen but that are corrupting the JSON.

Comment: @skrilled: I'm pretty sure jQuery uses `JSON.parse` if available.

Comment: console.log(return_result)

Comment: This is working for me 
`var obj = JSON.parse('[{"color": "black","product_name": "Prod2","revision": "apps/"},{"color": "green","product_name": "Prod1","revision": "dev/"}]'); alert(obj[0].color);`
Perhaps you should access to each obj element

Comment: @BrianDuncan console.log(return_result); returns (an empty string)

Comment: The problem was my PHP file not returning anything (empty). I removed the `function` and placed only the php code. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with `JSON` just set fourth parameter in `post()` method to `json`:

```
$.post('includes/package_filter.php', { /* params */ }, function(return_result) {                   
    // return_result[0].product_name;
}, 'json');
```

Comment: I tried that and I get no error but everything where you put // return_result[0].product_name; is not executed

Comment: @remyremy: As Qualcuno stated, use your browser developer tools to see what the exact response is that you receive.

Comment: @FelixKling I've tried and the Response tab is empty in Firebug. I guess nothing is returned.

Comment: @remyremy: Yep, then that's most likely the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Check the encoding of the response UTF-8 ASCII you may have Characters that are messing up with the parser.